# Sync data between 2 computers using 2 or more removable drives that are much smaller than the data itself

Tags: windows, file-synchronization

I need to sync large data between two PCs and my only (fast) option is USB drive much smaller than the total data to be synced.

I need a software that'll automatically manage the process of transferring the entire data in multiple passes, i.e. automatically making decisions of what part or which files to transfer in which pass etc.

Basically I want the process to be something like this:

1. Insert Drive-A in PC-A, let the software fill it up
2. Insert Drive-A in PC-B, let the software "unload" it
3. Meanwhile, insert Drive-B in PC-A, let the software fill that up
4. Now remove Drive-A from PC-B, insert Drive-B, and let that unload
5. Meanwhile, insert Drive-A back in PC-A, let the software fill that up

Repeat until all data is transferred.

OS: Windows. License: Any

Comment: I take it that neither machine is networked?

Comment: @Ring They're networked but only via WiFi which is much slower (effectively <1 MBPS, I've measured) compared to USB transfer (60-180 MBPS)